# Why is Azure AD B2C restricting the use of the 'for' attribute in custom UIs?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Does anyone know why the `sanitizerPolicy` applied by B2C does not have the `for` attribute listed within the `allowedAttributes` list or if it's possible to modify the policy? I cannot think of any real vulnerability with allowing use of that attribute but instead it's stripped by the HTML sanitization of the HTML retrieved from the custom UI source. There is very little documentation to be found on the sanitizerPolicy.

The `sanitizerPolicy` is complex property contained within the `SETTINGS` JavaScript object which is injected by the Expression framework (so B2C itself) into the B2C UI and used when loading remote content (e.g. custom UI HTML and CSS) for a specific content definition. The injected settings are then applied by JavaScript functions (e.g. sanitizeHTML) which are also injected by default by the Expression Framework. The functions and settings are used to restrict the HTML being served by the remote source (via the `LoadUri` property of the ContentDefinition in the Expression Framework). There is little or no documentation on this so no useful links can be provided

The current `allowedAttribute` array within the `sanitizerPolicy` is as follows:
`['id', 'class', 'href', 'name', 'data-*', 'aria-*', 'type', 'lang', 'src', 'sizes', 'role', 'placeholder', 'title', 'width', 'height', 'style']`

Context: My use case is that I would like to have a password policy toggle purely in CSS which makes use of a hidden checkbox and a label bound to the checkbox using the `for` attribute but alas no binding as the `for`attribute is stripped from the label element by the sanizterPolicy upon rendering my custom ui.

There is a *closed* GitHub [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9564) relating to a request to add proper documentation on this functionality. The location of that documentation is unknown nor is any link to other open tasks to delivery same provided.

Comment: When mentioned ‘allowedAttributes’ list, could you please kindly share with us where have you found ‘allowedAttributes’ list and that the ‘for’ attribute is not supported in the HTML content in the process of UI customization in B2C?  Any reference link would be helpful.

Comment: Also regarding sanitizerPolicy, could you please share more details about the policy? Is it a custom policy you used for UI customization?

Comment: [Document What is Allowed (Tags, Attributes, etc)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/9564) GitHub Issue to add documentation on this topic @TonyJu

Comment: And if [B2C allows JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples) why would there be any limits on HTML?   What's the detailed rationale behind all of this?  Yes, I know security, but give me an example. @TonyJu

Comment: @TonyJu - I added a little more context as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I just heard back from Azure support engineer to confirm that the ‘for’ attribute is not supported in customizing UIs under Azure B2C scenarios. Currently they have indicated that a better documentation regarding this behavior is needed for now.